# Accessing specific column using Eloquent & Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, laravel, eloquent

I'm teaching myself Laravel by building an application that, amongst other things, fetches data from default Wordpress tables, and I've run into a best-practices question that I'm not sure how to tackle.

I've got a very simple model for the User database that looks like this:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model
{
    public $table='wp_users';
    protected $primaryKey='user_id';
}
```

And I'm able to fetch it into an array using a line like `$users = User::all();` in my controller that I can then send into my view in any number of different ways.

Now; my question for best practices has to do with accessing multiple values from a particular column **or** from a set of columns from the database on a website.

Say I want to create a dropdown list that contains the `display_name` from the database as the ... well, displayed text, and the `user_login` as the option value that gets passed in the form.

In the "good old" days, I could do this with something like a `foreach` statement that pushes `<?php echo $whatever; ?>` into the relevant places in the html, but it's a *very* ugly solution. I mean ... just look at this stuff:

```
<?php foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value='" . $key . "'>" . $value['name'] . "</option>";
} ?>
```

Using Eloquent, I could do something like `Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'))`, and I'm sure there's a way of passing an array into this statement, but that's exactly my problem ... I just can't seem to figure out how to do it. How do I tell the `Form` statement to use `$users[0]->display_name` for the first entry, `$users[1]->display_name` for the second, etc... ?

Comment: Pass the data to the view and use blade to iterate the array and show it on view

Answer (score 0):

in your controller do

```
$users = User::get()->pluck('name','user_id');
```

in your form

```
Form::select('size', $users)
```

This will simply build your dropdown list for you.

Comment: If it works (I'm unable to test right now), this would be the far most elegant solution - but how does the `Form` statement know how to use `$users`? It has two columns, so does it automatically pick the first column as the option name and the second as display text? Can't find documentation on this...

Comment: It picks the first column as the value and the second as the key. Eloquent does this for you automatically

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you passed the data to the view and use Blade as the templating engine:

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="form">
    @foreach($formFields as $key => $val)
        <input name="{{ $key  }}" value=" {{ $val }}">
    @endforeach
</form>
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, since it would use *all* keys and their corresponding values, not just the two I'm interested in. But I suppose this has to be done in the controller, in that case, passing just the two columns I want to use instead of using the full $users array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old Laravel Form package by installing it from the Collective - https://laravelcollective.com/

Once you have that installed you can use the following to generate an array that will use the user_id as the value for each select option and display_name as the options text:

```
$users = User::where('something', 'something')->lists('display_name', 'user_id');
```

Then in your blade template:

```
{!! Form::select('users', $users) !!}
```

Comment: Sure, I've got the Form package up and running already, as indicated in my first post, but I'm confused about the array being passed to it in your code. How does it know to use `display_name` and `user_id` in their corresponding value/display fields?

Comment: @BrekiTomasson Because Form::select automatically generates the options for you based on an array format where the key is the value of the option and the value is the text. The User::lists() method returns an array, the second parameter (in this case 'user_id') lets you specify what to use as the key of that array.

Comment: Gotcha. How does your `$user` definition differ from `User::get()->pluck('name','user_id');` that @oseintow suggested in the comment above?

Comment: @BrekiTomasson lists() is an alias for pluck and is just more commonly found in tutorials and code examples when populating select lists. You could use either - pluck is probably the better method to use as lists has technically been deprecated as of 5.2 it seems.